# MSGRAPH file upload response

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, response

Hi I have successfully uploaded a file to onedrive using

PUT /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

I do get a driveItem returned

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
"value": [
    {....
```

However it seems to be from the parent of the parent id (the root in this case)

I was expecting it to return either a single drive item for the file just uploaded or perhaps driveitems for all in parent id

Is this what others see?

Have I misunderstood something?